# TexStudio Macro to lower case words

Tags: macros, texstudio

This macro

```
%SCRIPT
cursor.replaceSelectedText("\\gls{" + cursor.selectedText() + "}")
```

To enclose a term with \gls{}. How can I make the macro also make the word lowercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ECMAScript functions/methods are supported, hence the [string method `toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) does the job.

```js
%SCRIPT
cursor.replaceSelectedText("\\gls{" + cursor.selectedText().toLowerCase() + "}")
```